# Why getMeasuredWidth() returns 0?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my activity `onCreate()` method I created a `View` and hardcoded its width and height to be equal to 50. Then I call `measure` method. After that I expect that `getMeasuredWidth()` returns 50. But it returns 0.

```
    View v = new View(this);
    v.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(50, 50));

    final int spec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    v.measure(spec, spec);
    final int w = v.getMeasuredWidth();
    Log.e("aaa", String.valueOf(w)); // output is 0
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I force to calculate measured view's size? I do not want until it has been drawn, etc.

Comment: you may want to read again the documentation of `makeMeasureSpec`

Answer (score 3):

```
private void measureDimension() {
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
            int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();

        }
    });
}
```

You can call this method in `onCreate`.

Comment: Because, this can't be done during onCreate or onResume, as the duplicate explained.